# Cannot find Windows.Devices.Sensors on server machine

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, winrt-component

I have a C# desktop application using WinRT API, i.e. Windows.Sensors.Devices.Compass. The application can be built locally on a Windows  10 machine but it cannot be built on our build server which has Windows Server 2008 R2 installed.

I can see the path of the reference is to "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WinMetadata\Windows.Devices.winmd" which is not available on the build server.

How can I make this application built on the build machine?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can copy the .winmd files to my project and change the references to these files instead the ones from System32/WinMetadata/ folder. The build server can build the application now.